# File format not supported when sharing through whatsapp

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, share

```
    val share: Intent
    try {
        share = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareString)
        if (media != null) {
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, media)
            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            if (FileUtilities.isAnAudio(media.path)) {
                share.type = "audio/*"
            } else if (isVideo) {
                share.type = "video/*"
            } else {
                share.type = "image/*"
            }
        } else {
            share.type = "text/plain"
        }` 
   }
```

// Here media is the media uri

// Sharing for the video working fine but when I try to share an image I am getting the error that **file format not supported** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt3YM.png)

Comment: Use a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard like `image/*`. **You** are the one supplying the content, so it is **your job** to tell the other app **exactly** what type of content it is.